# PHP substring not working for intergers

Tags: php

I am trying to extract part of a number using sustr() but the following is not working:

```
$num = 012014;

echo substr($num, 0,2);
```

returns 51

BUT

```
$num = '012014';

echo substr($num, 0,2);
```

returns 01

I want it to return 01 can someone help me

Comment: Well, you can't write ``$num = 012014;`` to begin with. Did you skip your math classes?

Comment: `012014` is treated as an octal number. The value of `$num` is 5132.

Comment: `$num = 012014` equals to `$num = 5132`. [php integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

Comment: Thanks Rikesh. It has worked the problem was putting a o at the beggining of a number. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is is not a normal number, when it's prepended with a zero (0). Then it's an **octal number**

If you treat $num as a string, it'll work.

```
$num = '012014';
echo substr($num, 0,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must declare the variable as string like this.

```
$num = '012014'; 
echo substr( (string)$num, 0, 2 );
```

Comment: No need for the cast in the `substr` call

Answer (score -1):

Ooops I didn't notice the leading zero. You should just define $num as a string

```
$num = '0123';
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
$num = 123424;
$num = (string)$num;

echo substr($num, 0,2);
```

Comment: This wont work with the original number: http://codepad.org/z2qAPMZb

Comment: i have tested code on this " http://writecodeonline.com/php/" and it works

Comment: Have you tested using `$num = 012014;`? Your code will not work for numbers beginning with a `0` because PHP will treat them as an octal number.